# MVC: List being deleted without any code being executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Well guys, this problem just baffles me. I hope someone can explain to me what is going on because I think I'm losing my mind... :)

The situation is as follows:
In my Index method (MVC2 application), I query the entire content of a table in my database, and insert it into the 'temp' variable. I then narrow down the list based on what parameters have been passed to my method.

```
if (int.TryParse(costcenter, out tempint) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(costcenter))
     {
            Trace.Write("From " + temp.Count());
            temp = temp.Where(x => x.tbl_CostCenters.Id == tempint);
            Trace.WriteLine(" to " + temp.Count());
     }

if (int.TryParse(supplier, out tempint) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(supplier))
            {
                temp = temp.Where(x => x.tbl_EquipmentType.tbl_Suppliers.id == tempint);
            }

            Trace.WriteLine(" to " + temp.Count());
```

These parameters are passed as string, so I convert them to ints, then use a query to filter based on the values (if any). What I noticed was, when I select a CostCenter to filter on (and nothing else, all other variables are null), no results were return. I added some tracing to check how many items should be displayed. Given the 3 Trace.Write command in there, i expected my output to be the following:

```
From 8989 to 65
 to 65
```

However, what I get is:

```
From 8989 to 65
 to 0
```

Which means something is going amiss in the 'supplier'-filter. I debugged it and stepped through piece by piece, the program does the following:

- After writing the " to 65" string, the program jumps to the "if(...supplier...)"
- Debugging watch: **tempint** = 0, **supplier** = null
- The program skips directly to the next Trace.Writeline as the evaluation is false
- Suddenly, my temp variable contains no elements.

I'm puzzled by this because my method is not executing any command related to the temp variable, yet it gets emptied.
Also, when I comment the "supplier"-filter (the entire IF-block), the code work. The error is occuring in the "Supplier"-filter.

Anyone have an idea as to why this is occuring? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

If I comment out only the *content* of the "supplier"-if-block, and keep the if-block itself, it also goes amiss. So the problem is occuring in the evaluation of the if-statement. Am I losing my mind here? :(

**FURTHER UPDATE**

Well, I fixed it by adding .ToList() to every statement so that `temp` is now an IEnumerable rather than an IQueryable.

I'm still puzzled as to why this is happening. Can anyone explain why it doesn't work without converting `temp` to a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out that you need to do a .ToList(), else your query keeps working by reference rather than by value.

Always do a .ToList() :)